# What is LOCAL_SERIAL in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have been intending to model a Bank application database and want to make sure, the database remain consistent at every node.
Came across LOCAL_QUORUM and LOCAL_SERIAL, when can we use it?
I know LOCAL_QUORUM (n/2+1) consistency is required, what about LOCAL_SERIAL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LOCAL_SERIAL` and `SERIAL` are used for so-called [lightweight transactions (LWTs)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntLtwtTransactions.html), when replicas need to coordinate between them before applying the change. `SERIAL` requires all replicas in all data centers to coordinate, and `LOCAL_SERIAL` - only replicas in the local data center.

But you should be very careful with LWTs - they should be applied in very limited number of cases, as they could significantly impact performance.

Comment: Would you suggest it for a bank's money transaction ? or would Quorum would do just fine ?

Comment: it's not a real transaction, like in RDBMS. You can solve such task other way, for example, like here: https://github.com/PatrickCallaghan/datastax-mailpay

Comment: Thansks, let me have a look

Comment: Wouldn't `serial` be `quorum` and `local_serial` be `local_quorum` in the end?

Comment: It’s similar, but not the same, as it’s not just counting the number of answers